# Iterate through HashMap of ArrayList of Directed Edges, extract Directed Edges data

Tags: java, arraylist, graph, iterator, hashmap

I'm trying to iterate through a HashMap contain ArrayLists of Directed Edges, for a Edgeweighted Directed Graph.  I've followed instructions from similar questions, but it's not working correctly.

I want to:
Iterate through the HashMap, retrieve each ArrayList.
Then iterate through the directedEdges in the ArrayList.
Print out the Directed Edge, which has the following toString method:

```
public String toString(){  
    return String.format("%s->%s %d", v, w, weight);
     }
```

Below full EdgeDirectedGraph class, toString method I'm querying is at the bottom.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class EdgeWeightedDiGraph{
private static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
private int V;
private int E;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<DirectedEdge>> adjacencyList;

public EdgeWeightedDiGraph(String filename, String delim){  
  BufferedReader br = null;
      try{
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
         E = 0;
         V = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
         //System.out.println(V);
         String line = null;
         this.adjacencyList = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<DirectedEdge>>();
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             //adj = (Bag<Integer>[]) new Bag[V];
             String arr[] = line.split(delim); // properties
             String v = arr[0];
             String w = arr[1];
             int e =  Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
             DirectedEdge dEdge = new DirectedEdge(v, w, e); 
             addEdge(dEdge);
             System.out.println(dEdge.from()+dEdge.to()+dEdge.weight());
             }   
          }  
      catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
             System.out.println("Error: File not found");
             Logger.getLogger(EdgeWeightedDiGraph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }       
      catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(EdgeWeightedDiGraph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
      finally{
         try {
             br.close();
         }
         catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(EdgeWeightedDiGraph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
     }

}

  public HashMap getMap(){
      return adjacencyList;
  }

 public int V(){  
     return V;  
 }
 public int E(){  
     return E;  
 }
 public void addEdge(DirectedEdge e)
 {
     String v = e.from();
     String w = e.to();
     ArrayList<DirectedEdge> item = new ArrayList<DirectedEdge>();
     item.add(e);
     adjacencyList.put(v, item);
     System.out.println(v+item);
     E++; 
 }

 public Iterable<DirectedEdge> adjacencyList(String v){  
     return adjacencyList.get(v);  
 }

 public Iterable<DirectedEdge> edges()
 {

public String toString() {
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      s.append(V + " " + E + NEWLINE);
      for (HashMap.Entry<String, ArrayList<DirectedEdge>> entry : adjacencyList.entrySet()){
          ArrayList<DirectedEdge> arrList = entry.getValue();
          for(DirectedEdge e :  arrList){
              s.append(e + "  "); }
          s.append(NEWLINE);
       }
      return s.toString();
  }
}
```

Below is the output:
I can see that the Directed Edges are being added to the graph, but only half are printing out in the toString() method.

```
Print out of edges being added
A[A->B 5]
AB5, 
B[B->C 4] 
BC4, 
C[C->D 8] 
CD8, 
D[D->C 8]
DC8, 
D[D->E 6] 
DE6 ,
A[A->D 5] 
AD5, 
C[C->E 2]
CE2, 
E[E->B 3] 
EB3, 
A[A->E 7] 
AE7
```

"toString() output : A->E 7 B->C 4 C->E 2 D->E 6 E->B 3 "

Comment: Sorry I was having trouble with the formatting whilst trying to add the rest of my output, then it got messed up and now i can't edit for 90 minutes apparently ?

Comment: Trying to add output from the toString() :
A->E 7   
B->C 4  
C->E 2  
D->E 6  
E->B 3

Comment: Can you please mark back up as I was desperately trying to fix it up as you marked me down, I kept getting error messages about code, trying to include the results in my comment above, so I was moving things around

Comment: Great, so now two people have marked me down, is that for the same thing? Because I really don't want to wait two days to use a bounty, when I just was having trouble using the formatting

Comment: thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels. I've now included the whole class, hope that's not too much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are always creating a new `DirectedEdge` list when you add and edge instead of using the existing list if it exists.

```
public void addEdge(DirectedEdge e)
{
    String v = e.from();
    String w = e.to();

    // Check if there is already an edge array
    ArrayList<DirectedEdge> item = adjacencyList.get(v);
    if(item == null) {
        // Does not exist, create it
        item = new ArrayList<DirectedEdge>();
    }
    item.add(e);
    adjacencyList.put(v, item);
    System.out.println(v+item);
}
```